# Match two consecutive lines using Regex and Bash features only

Tags: regex, bash

What Regular Expression(s) can you use to match two consecutive lines?
The aim is not to use any packages like `awk` or `sed` but only use pure RegExp inside a shell script.

Example, I would like to ensure the word "hello" is immediately followed by "world" in the next line.

Acceptance criteria:

- "hello" is not to have any spaces before it
- "world" must have at least 1 or more space before it.

```sh
#/bin/bash

file=./myfile.txt

regex='^hello'

[[ `cat $file` =~ $regexp ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

myfile.txt

```
abc is def
hello
 world
cde is efg
```

Comment: Why not AWK? It's going to make things very easy.

Comment: I am doing this inside a light weight docker container. Otherwise it would be easy. It's for my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is pure bash way:

```
file='./myfile.txt'
[[ $(<$file) =~ hello$'\n'[[:blank:]]*world ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

```
yes
```

Here `$'\n'` matches a new line and `[[:blank:]]*` matches 0+ tabs or spaces.

If you want to be more precise then use:

```
[[ $(<file) =~ (^|$'\n')hello$'\n'[[:blank:]]*world($'\n'|$) ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

However `grep` or `awk` are much better tools for this job.

Comment: How can you place a bound so that "hello" can have anything after it on same line like "hello something", but world cannot have anything after it, "world" only.

Comment: For that, you just need to add `.*` after `hello` to allow it to match a line starting with `hello` i.e. `[[ $(<file) =~ (^|$'\n')hello.*$'\n'[[:blank:]]*world($'\n'|$) ]]`